# Can I inject my database handler into FastAPI's APIRouter?

Tags: python, mongodb, rest, dependency-injection, fastapi

FastAPI [clearly documents](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/bigger-applications/#dependencies) the ability to add dependencies to multiple routes by including them in the `APIRouter` object creation step:

```
router = APIRouter(
    prefix="/items",
    tags=["items"],
    dependencies=[Depends(get_token_header)],
    responses={404: {"description": "Not found"}},
)
```

Currently I inject my database handler into each endpoint like so:

```
@router.get("/")
def list_workflows(db: MongoManager = Depends(get_database)):
```

and then access the database via the `db` variable. My question is: can I include the `get_database` function as a dependency in the `APIRouter`, and if so, how do I access the database within the endpoint function?

Comment: You access it by defining the dependency as you already did. That's usually the way to do it (or maybe better, depend on the service itself, which in turn depends on `get_database` - so that your controller isn't concerned with the database at all, just the service class necessary. You can also use `request.state` and configure the db in a middleware - then access it through `request.state.db` - but that will be just as much to type, and a lot less expressive of what you're trying to do. I'd say that the most sensible thing to do if you'd like to change, would be to move to dedicated services.

Comment: It is not recommended to access the database directly from web services. They should be in a different layer. Normally you call application services from the web services and the application services access the databases through repositories, so even those don't access the databases directly. Though if your application is very simple you can spare a few layers and write spaghetti code.